# SignalR closing connection when deployed to Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an Angular app with SignalR and .NET core in the back end. The app works locally fine but when I deploy to Azure App Service. The front end connects with the signalR but soon after front end receives close message from server and connection is dropped. After that any page that tries to send a command (invoke) to the server fails. The following is the log after deployment.

[Logs after connecting to signal R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzGIj.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the front-end logs, we can find the connection was established at first, and the connection was dropped immedidately by server. So we need to [enable server side logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0#server-side-logging) and find more details.

**Trouleshooting steps**

1. Increase the size for SingalR and give it a try.

   ```
   builder.services.AddSignalR(e => {
       e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
   });
   ```
2. Check the code and find what happend after connecting successfully.
3. Check the database connectionstring (or redis), maybe you inject some service inside your hub, if you using the local connectionstring in azure, it will give us the NullReferenceException.